# Why doesn't my <div> slide with these jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reduce my `<div>` size when I click on a `<a>` . But it doesn t work.

**Javascript code** 
(divheight is a global variable)

```javascript
function jamsho(id) {
  var idd=id.substr(1);
  alert(document.getElementById(idd).style.height);

  if(document.getElementById(idd).style.height != 30) {
    $(id).stop().animate({height:30}, 700);
    divheight=document.getElementById(idd).style.height;
  } else if (document.getElementById(idd).style.height == "30px") {
    $(id).animate({height:divheight}, 700);
  }
}
```

And call the function :

```html
<div class="linkbox" id="linksbox">
    <a id="Titr" onClick="jamsho('#linksbox')"> پیوند ها</a>
    <a href="http://rawanonline.com" target="_newtab">سایت روان آنلاین</a>
</div>
```

Comment: what's with the strange mix of jquery and not?

Comment: what ? I don't understand !

Comment: You're also not consistent within your own code:  `document.getElementById(idd).style.height != 30` (integer) vs `document.getElementById(idd).style.height == "30px"` (string)… See @DontVoteMeDown's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ditch the onclick, ditch the vanilla js. It's as simple as follows:

## jsFiddle Example

### HTML

```
<div class="linkbox" id="linksbox">
        <a id="Titr"> پیوند ها</a>
        <a href="http://rawanonline.com" target="_newtab">سایت روان آنلاین</a>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$('#Titr').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var par = $(this).parent();
    par.animate({height:par.height()==30?'':30},700);
});
```

And if you want something more "dynamic":

```
$('.linkbox').on('click', 'a:first', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var par = $(this).parent();
    par.animate({height:par.height()==30?'':30},700);
});
```

Keep in mind, last solution only works for jQuery versions 1.7 and above, for older version, replace `.on` with `.delegate`

Answer (score 2):

You're sure that this condition `document.getElementById(idd).style.height!=30` is satisfied?

I believe that the property `height` comes as *string* with the "px" sufix. [See this](http://jsfiddle.net/mhcgolds/gtzKd/).

So, to work it may be `if (document.getElementById(idd).style.height!="30px")`.

BTW, is a best pratice to use *only* jQuery or pure Javascript, not mix them.

Comment: jQuery `.height()` comes as in integer

Comment: @SpYk3HH yeah I know. But that wasn't his case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can apply jQuery animations to non-jQuery Objects

```
function jamsho(id) {
alert($(id).css("height");

 if($(id).css("height")!=30)
 {
    $(id).stop().animate({height:30},700);
    divheight=$(id).css("height");

 }
 else if ($(id).css("height")==30)
 {
    $(id).animate({height:divheight},700);

 }
}
```

Comment: Can you point out specifically where in the code this is happening?  I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery for all of the function, instead of part of it:

```
function jamsho(id)
{
    var $this = $(id);
    alert($this.height());

    if ($this.height() != 30)
    {
        $this.stop().animate({height:30},700);
        divheight = $this.height();
    }
    else if ($this.height() == 30)
    {
        $this.animate({height:divheight},700);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JamesMontagne, that isn't true. Look closely at his code. `document.getElementById(idd)` and `$(id)` refer to the same DOM object, because `idd="linksbox"` and `id="#linksbox"`.

Comment: Can you describe how it's not working? Is there an error message of any kind?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var $div = $('#linksbox'),
    divHeight = $div.height();

$('#Titr').click(function() {
    if (!$div.hasClass('expanded')) {
        $div.animate({height: 40}, 700, function() {
            $(this).addClass('expanded');
        });
    }
    else {
        $div.animate({height: divHeight}, 700, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('expanded');
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqEZ5/

A few notes:

- no need to use `document.getElementById` with jQuery
- don't use inline event handlers `onClick`.

Hope it helps.